issues putting/copying local file to hdfs in docker
To put in context, I am working on a solution that requires data collection using kafka, and then storing that data into HDFS. The producer part in kafka is already working, but when it comes to the consumer part, the script consumes the data but can't put it into the hdfs.
I tried 2 ways of doing it and none of them works. in the first one, I tried consumming directly from the topic to the hdfs using this code:
# Define the Kafka consumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'testing-topic',
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')
)

# HDFS client 
hdfs_client = InsecureClient('http://localhost:50070', user='root')  

# HDFS file path
hdfs_file_path = '/data/voix_data.csv'

print("Connecting to HDFS...")

try:
    # Open HDFS file for writing
    with hdfs_client.write(hdfs_file_path, encoding='utf-8') as writer:
        # Write CSV header
        writer.write('final_anon_mdn,profile_id,subprofile,product_name,gamme,marche,segment,billing_type,'
                     'final_anon_party_account,final_anon_party_customer,final_anon_contract_id,event_type,'
                     'call_dir,termination_type,network_type,dest_type,other_operator,zone,country,ci,district,'
                     'city,region,num_events,sum_event_minutes,traffic_days,last_timestamp,last_date,start_date,'
                     'end_date,source,id_month\n')
        print("Header written to HDFS.")
        
        for message in consumer:
            # Print the received message
            print(f"Received message: {message.value}")  
            # Write each line to HDFS
            writer.write(message.value + '\n')

but nothing happens.
And then I tried the second method which to store the data into a local file and then copy that file to the hdfs, but still doesn't work, it gives this as an out put: 'copyFromLocal: `/data/voix_data.csv': No such file or directory'
and for the script that I used for this method:
def kafka_to_local_file(kafka_container_id, topic_name, local_file_path):
    # Define the Kafka console consumer command
    kafka_cmd = [
        "docker", "exec", "-i", kafka_container_id,
        "kafka-console-consumer.sh", "--bootstrap-server", "localhost:9092",
        "--topic", topic_name, "--from-beginning", "--timeout-ms", "30000"
    ]
    
    # Open the local file for writing
    with open(local_file_path, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as local_file:
        csv_writer = csv.writer(local_file)
        
        # Run the Kafka command and capture the output
        process = subprocess.Popen(kafka_cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        
        for line in process.stdout:
            # Decode line and split CSV-like string into list
            decoded_line = line.decode('utf-8').strip()
            print(f"Received line: {decoded_line}")  # Debug print
            if decoded_line:  # Ensure the line is not empty
                row = decoded_line.split(';')
                csv_writer.writerow(row)
        
        process.wait()
        stderr = process.communicate()[1]
        if stderr:
            print(f"Error: {stderr.decode('utf-8')}")

def upload_to_hdfs(local_file_path, hdfs_file_path, hdfs_container_id):
    # Define the HDFS put command
    hdfs_cmd = [
        "docker", "exec", "-i", hdfs_container_id,
        "hdfs", "dfs", "-copyFromLocal", local_file_path, hdfs_file_path
    ]
    
    # Run the HDFS command to upload the file
    result = subprocess.run(hdfs_cmd, capture_output=True, text=True)
    if result.returncode != 0:
        print(f"Failed to upload to HDFS: {result.stderr}")
    else:
        print(f"Data uploaded to HDFS: {result.stdout}")

# Define the Kafka consumer
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'testing-topic',  # Topic name
    bootstrap_servers=['localhost:9092'],
    auto_offset_reset='earliest',
    value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')  # Deserialize data from UTF-8 encoded string
)

# HDFS client
hdfs_client = InsecureClient('http://localhost:50070', user='root')

# Local file path and HDFS file path
local_file_path = '/mnt/c/Users/Asus/Desktop/internship/infra/local_test.csv'
hdfs_file_path = '/user/hadoop/data/voix_data.csv'

# Run the functions to transfer data
kafka_container_id = 'bb20bf20183711348208d7a1bf9ae28b69a876419ef79cb1c3f3c66bf5c4d036'
hdfs_container_id = '7bbff9c48e913340cbc97abaa27fc23a8362b2670e714010d75b06458209f4f5'
topic_name = 'testing-topic'  # Replace with your Kafka topic name

print("Starting data transfer from Kafka to local CSV file...")
kafka_to_local_file(kafka_container_id, topic_name, local_file_path)
print("Local CSV file created.")

print("Uploading CSV file to HDFS...")
upload_to_hdfs(local_file_path, hdfs_file_path, hdfs_container_id)


Try really really hard to avoid directly invoking docker commands from within your program: to do it at all, you gain the ability to docker run a container that takes over the host system.  You should not need docker exec in routine use either, reserve it for debugging tasks.  Your first code block looks like the right approach (the hard-coded localhost should be parameterizable); can you tell which part of the Kafka/HDFS setup is failing?

@DavidMaze thank you for your help. I tried the docker commands because I couldn't any solution for the first code. And for the failing part in the first code, I would say it's mostly the part where I try to put the data consumed from topic to the hdfs, it's like the connection fails or it doesn't find the path or something like that.

@DavidMaze this is the error I get:
HTTPConnectionPool(host='3624428fe2f1', port=50075): Max retries exceeded with url: /webhdfs/v1/data/voix_data.csv?op=CREATE&user.name=root&namenoderpcaddress=namenode:8020&overwrite=false&user.name=root (Caused by NameResolutionError("<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fa2c68e1a80>: Failed to resolve '3624428fe2f1' ([Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution)"))
